# Oracle INSERT multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, insert-into

My statement will insert two out of the four student IDs. The ones that are inserted are Id's that already exist with another section number. I cant figure out why the other two are not inserted.

```
INSERT INTO enrollment
    (student_id,section_id,enroll_date,created_by,created_date,modified_by,modified_date)
SELECT
    student_id,'48',SYSDATE,'KABEL',SYSDATE,'KABEL',SYSDATE
FROM enrollment
WHERE student_id IN ('375','137','266','382');
```

Comment: because they don't exist in the enrollment table... you are inserting based on the results of a select, if you can't select the 2 students, you won't be able to insert them using that statement.  Also, you should know that if whatever student already has more than 1 row in that table (e.g.: 5 rows), then your statement will attempt to insert that student 5 times!  Doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: your select and insert statement using the same table `enrollment`

Comment: That makes sense I changed the from table to the Student table that contains the student_id's and it worked. I thought that the table had to match for the specified values. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much wrong in your query. You are typo or by mistake choose INSERT table and SELECT query from one table as this does not make any sense, to select from one table and insert into same table.

Your select and Insert statement using the same table `enrollment`.

These should be two different table.

```
INSERT INTO enrollment <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-------Here Problem
  (student_id,section_id,enroll_date,created_by,created_date,
      modified_by,modified_date)
SELECT
    student_id,'48',SYSDATE,'KABEL',SYSDATE,'KABEL',SYSDATE
FROM enrollment   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-------Here Problem
WHERE student_id IN ('375','137','266','382');
```